# Can you include a static lib (.a) in another static lib with ar?

Tags: gcc, ld, unix-ar

Let's say I've got a couple of .o files in a directory that get ar'ed into a static library:

```
ar cr libstuff.a a.o b.o
```

In another directory there are a couple of other .o files that need to be ar'ed in addition to the libstuff.a created above:

```
ar cr libother.a c.o d.o /path/to/stuff/libstuff.a
```

I thought that including libstuff.a would work there, however I get undefined symbols (that should be defined in libstuff.a) when I do that and then later try to link wtih libother.a.  (using g++)

Is there a way to combine a .a into a static library like this or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It you run 'ar t' on the new lib, you will find that it contains a copy of the old lib. Not useful.

You need to extract the input lib, add the new .o files, and then build a new lib with all the contents.